# Most elegant/ simple way to apply a function to every element of a recursive data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Context (probably not really needed, you might be able to skip this, question is at the bottom): I'm preparing for an exam in Haskell, and there's likely going to be a question where we are given a data type and have to apply a function to every element of that data type. 
For example, it could be something like

```
data ToDoList = Task String | HighPriority [ToDoList] | LowPriority [ToDoList] | FreeTime [ToDoList]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and the exercise could be "Write a function that takes a renaming function f :: String -> String and a ToDoList and returns an updated ToDoList where every task has been renamed according to f."

Possible solutions:

In the solutions from previous years, they solve the exercise quite cleverly by using a mix of pattern matching, recursion and map. They define cases for the atomic values and for the composite/ recursive data types, they map the function over the array of the data type (I can provide examples if needed).

For my rather convoluted approach (that doesn't work either), I also define base cases for the atomic values, but then try to pattern match the arrays, call the function on the elements and append them afterwards; one case of the function definition would be (doesn't work):

```
rename (HighPriority []) = HighPriority []
rename (HighPriority (t:ts)) = HighPriority ((rename f t):[rename f (HighPriority ts)])
```

My Question: what are some simple and quick ways to iterate a function over recursive data types?

Edit: sorry for the confusion, yes I meant to define the data type with a "ToDoList" list.

Comment: At the moment you only define `Task` as a _value_ constructor (`= Task String`), but then use it as _type_ (`HighPriority [Task]`). Please fix/clarify.

Comment: Looks like a case for free monads... That being said, that data definition is rather unintuitive. I wouldn't implement a tasklist this way. Also, I'm assuming you meant `HighPriority [ToDoList]`, as `Task` is a constructor, and not a type.

Comment: You would be more likely to get something like `type Task = String; data ToDoList = ToDoList [Task] [Task] [Task] [Task]` (where the four lists are high priority tasks, low priority tasks, free-time tasks, and other tasks).

Comment: sorry for the bad example. I translated the exercise from a context where it made sense to be used that way (in the original exercise the data type represented logical formulas). For me, the important part is having a quick and reliable way to iterate over these recursive structures that I can apply in my exam

Answer (score 4):

For that data type, you can apply the `String` value to the function `f` in the `Task` case, and use `map` for all the other cases.

```
rename :: (String -> String) -> ToDoList -> ToDoList
rename f (Task x)          = Task (f x)
rename f (HighPriority xs) = HighPriority (map (rename f) xs)
rename f (LowPriority xs)  = LowPriority (map (rename f) xs)
rename f (FreeTime xs)     = FreeTime (map (rename f) xs)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, that's how they do it in the official solutions. I thought there might be a simpler method, but this seems like the way to go, so I'll probably just do that if the question comes up

Answer (score 1):

While this would not be a suitable answer for an exam, for future Stack Overflow users who have a similar problem in real-world code, it's worth pointing out that the `uniplate` package handles this kind of problem quite nicely.  You must give your data type appropriate `Uniplate` instances; the easiest way is to derive `Data` instances and import the `Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data` package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data

data ToDoList
  = Task String
  | HighPriority [ToDoList]
  | LowPriority [ToDoList]
  | FreeTime [ToDoList]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Data)
```

After this, you can write `rename` using the `transform` function from `uniplate` by defining a helper function that makes only the desired local changes:

```
rename :: (String -> String) -> ToDoList -> ToDoList
rename f = transform f'
  where f' (Task s) = (Task (f s))
        f' x = x
```

Note that the helper function `f' :: ToDoList -> ToDoList` only modifies task strings while passing everything else through unchanged, but the `transform` function ensures it will be applied recursively throughout the data structure wherever a `ToDoList` appears:

```
> import Data.Char
> rename (map toUpper) $ HighPriority [LowPriority [Task "one", Task "two"], Task "three"]
HighPriority [LowPriority [Task "ONE",Task "TWO"],Task "THREE"]
```